# How to match all rows in a table in which an interval intersects the `start_time` and `end_time` columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals

I have table with `start_time` and `end_time` colums both set to timestamp with timezone type. This table contains consecutive intervals, i.e. `end_time` of one row is the `start_time` of the following one.

Now, I need to select all rows that intersect a specific interval (two timestamps).

For example, a table could look like this:

```sql
 id |         start_time         |          end_time
----+----------------------------+----------------------------
 1  | 2022-01-23 15:00:00.000+00 | 2022-01-23 16:00:00.000+00
 2  | 2022-01-23 16:00:00.000+00 | 2022-01-23 17:00:00.000+00
 3  | 2022-01-23 17:00:00.000+00 | 2022-01-23 18:00:00.000+00
 4  | 2022-01-23 18:00:00.000+00 | 2022-01-23 19:00:00.000+00
```

I’d like to select all row which intersect with the interval starting at `2022-01-23 16:23:00.000+00` and ending at `2022-01-23 18:44:00.000+00`, i.e. row IDs 2-4.

I can do it make it using three SQL commands:

- get the ID of row in where the first timestamp is;
- get the ID of row in where the second timestamp is;
- select all rows based on the previous IDs.

However, neither of the search times might be included in any of the intervals in the table (like any timestamp before `2022-01-23 15:00:00.000+00` or after `2022-01-23 19:00:00.000+00`).

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres knows [range data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) (which you could use in your table) and also a range overlap operator [`&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html).

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat
       WHERE tstzrange(start_time, end_time)
             && '[2022-01-23 16:23:00.000+00, 2022-01-23 18:44:00.000+00]'::tstzrange;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works as I wanted. Today I rad about the range data types, but I didn’t know about the range overlap operator (and other range operators). Thanks for sharing the links to the docs with me!

Comment: Actually, there is an issue if one of the dates is the same as one of the `start_time`/`end_time` in the table: it returns the following/previous interval too (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70826499/how-to-match-all-rows-in-a-table-in-which-an-interval-intersects-the-start-time/70826650#comment125210890_70826565)).

Comment: @tukusejssirs: Yes, you didn't mention if the boundaries are inclusive or exclusive. You may need to tweak here a little according to your needs.

Comment: @tukusejssirs: See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT) how to specify inclusive or exclusive boundaries with `tstzrang()`. In the casted string representation it's done by changing the brackets at the ends. You could really make your columns ranges from the start, then they already encode the inclusiveness of the boundaries and leave no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE start_time < '2022-01-23 18:44:00.000+00' AND end_time > '2022-01-23 16:23:00.000+00'
```

So `start_time` has to be less than the **end** of the search interval and `end_time` has to be greater than the **start** of the interval.

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ET43MEpTCjMZeXzeJbx5g/0)

Output:

| id | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-01-23T16:00:00.000Z | 2022-01-23T17:00:00.000Z |
| 3 | 2022-01-23T17:00:00.000Z | 2022-01-23T18:00:00.000Z |
| 4 | 2022-01-23T18:00:00.000Z | 2022-01-23T19:00:00.000Z |

Comment: Have you read my question until the very end? … I know I can do what you say, but there is a change there the searched `start_time` is outside of the oldest `start_time` in the table and same is true (but in reverse) for `end_time`.

Comment: @tukusejssirs Could you specify a counterexample, where my query works incorrectly while the accepted answer's query is correct?

Comment: Here you go (tested on the DB Fiddle you provided): `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE start_time < '2022-01-22 18:44:00.000+00' AND end_time > '2022-01-23 16:23:00.000+00';`.

Comment: You confused values, you should do this `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE start_time < '2022-01-23 16:23:00.000+00' AND end_time > '2022-01-22 18:44:00.000+00';`.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer: `start_time` has to be less than the `end` of the search interval and `end_time` has to be greater than the `start` of the interval.

Comment: And, if you are worried about performance, I recommend using this simplest solution instead of constructing range by `tstzrange()`, this solution is faster when you have many rows in your intervals table because you don't need to construct a range object for each row.

Comment: Actually, you’re right. … I have found a difference between your answer and the one from @stickybit: `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE start_time < '2022-01-23 16:00:00.000+00' AND end_time > '2022-01-22 18:44:00.000+00';` returns a single row (what I want), but `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE tstzrange(start_time, end_time) && '[2022-01-22 18:44:00.000+00, 2022-01-23 16:00:00.000+00]'::tstzrange;` returns two (as the end timestamp matches `start_time` of the additional row).

Comment: As for the performance, would that be an issue if I converted the table to use `tstzrange` as column type? What would be faster?

Comment: You can test it yourself.